# Initalizing a Go Gin server in Google Cloud Functions

Tags: go, google-cloud-functions, go-gin

I'm running a Gin HTTP server in Google Cloud Functions, but I don't know if im correctly initalizing the server. I'm new to Go so I don't know if I understand this correctly.

So the Google Cloud Functions Go runtime (1.13.8 beta) expects a function that implements the `type HandlerFunc` interface from `net/http`.

```
func HelloHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)
```

So my function looks like this:

```
func Hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    router.ServeHTTP(w, r) // ServeHTTP conforms to the http.Handler interface (https://godoc.org/github.com/gin-gonic/gin#Engine.ServeHTTP)
}
```

And my init function:

> [Use a func init() function to initialize values when a new instance of your function starts up. Note that code in the func init() function runs before your function receives its first request.](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/go-runtime#one-time_initialization)

```
var router *gin.Engine
func init() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.POST("/my/route", MyHandler)
    router.Run()
}
```

Everything works as expected when deployed, but I want to know if I have missed something or if I could do it more correctly?

Answer (score 0):

"ADD comment:
From the source code, I understand that you intended to write a HTTP function by including the third party Go - Gin Web framework.I can see that you followed [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing#http_functions) usin funct_int to initial the function. As you confirmed that, the function is running as expected.

However, it seems the dependency you implemented is not the same way as the best practice offered by the [Cloud Function documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-go#using_go_modules). Coud Function allows you to specify dependencies in Go. You can add the Gin WebFramewok source to GOPATH as the third party dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You could instantiate the Gin Engine and then register the "ServerHandler" directly as Cloud Function:

```
import (
    "github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-go/functions"
)

func init() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.POST("/my/route", MyHandler)
    functions.HTTP("HelloHTTP", router.Handler().ServeHTTP)
}
```